# UINav Bars and Search Bars in iOS 12

Tags: uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem, searchbar, ios12

I have an old ObjC iOS 9.3 App I am updating to iOS 12 and the iPhone X series.
The main view is a UIViewController with an embedded UITableView using STCollapseTableView. The table has a UISearchController customized with a search bar with a segmentedControl with buttons in addition to the usual textField and Cancel button. The Table is initially offset up by the height of the search block to hide it until the user drags the table down. All very vanilla and was working fine in the older OS.

Now:
The initial display of the tableview is fine on ViewDidLoad & Appear.
Initial drag down of the table works and search bar displays just the textfield and cancel button as desired.
First Issue: tapping textfield to gain focus there moves the search entry textfield and cancel button up, draws the segmented control as desired under them, then moves the whole search bar up into the Nav area by approximately the height of the search bar plus buttons. This separates the tableView from the search bar filling with background white space.
At this point, the cancel button still works, and its action moves the tableview back up to the search bar.

Text entry and search & limit features still work fine and fill the tableview appropriately.

Second BIG Issue: After user selects a detail View from the search results and returns to the main tableView, the search bar is now offset further up inside the Nav/Status bar with (iPhoneX) the textfield under the notch and the Cancel button under the battery status and untouchable or iPhone8 with searchBar barely visible at top of screen, way past safe area. This shift up occurs on iOS 12 devices, but not on iOS 10.3.3 devices.

Here is relevant code:
 Search Controller definition in MainVC

```
    // Here's where we create our UISearchController

    self.MySearchResultsController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.MySearchResultsController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [self.MySearchResultsController inputAssistantItem];
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];

    self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"",@"",@"",@""];
    id temp = [UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]];
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [temp setImage:img forSegmentAtIndex: 1];
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [temp setImage:img forSegmentAtIndex: 3];
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    [temp setImage:img forSegmentAtIndex: 2];

    self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    [self.MySearchResultsController.inputAccessoryView reloadInputViews];
    [self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    // Add the UISearchBar to the top header of the table view
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar;
    // Hides search bar initially.  When the user pulls down on the list, the search bar is revealed.
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];

    // It is usually good to set the presentation context.
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.MySearchResultsController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.MySearchResultsController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.searchController = _MySearchResultsController;
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
        [self.MySearchResultsController setActive:YES];
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar;
//        [self presentSearchController:_MySearchResultsController];
    }
```

Also in Main TableVC is the unwind from detailVC

```
-(IBAction)unwindFromNewDetailViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue {
    NewDetailViewController *dVC = [segue sourceViewController];
    NSIndexPath *newPath = dVC.returningIndexPath;
    if (newPath == nil) {
        newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)0 inSection:(NSInteger)0];
    }
    if (_inFilterMode) {
        newPath = _selectedIndexPath;
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.MySearchResultsController.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView openSection:newPath.section animated:YES];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                  animated:YES];
}
```

and here is the segue back from DetailVC: viewWillDisappear{}

```
if (_inSearchMode) {
    p = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)0 inSection:(NSInteger)0];
}
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindNewDetailToMainTable" sender:self];
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on my miscoding or on how to forcibly reposition searchBar and navBar on screen.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?